# Vue computed does not work

Tags: vue.js, vue-directives

I use Vue Devtools.For example when i change numbers this way on console `wm.numbers[0]=6` and i refresh Vue Devtools and look at, numbers has changed but evenNumbers has not changed.What is the problem?

Javascript Code:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data: {
    numbers: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
  },
  computed: {
    evenNumbers: function () {
      return this.numbers.filter(function (number) {
        return number % 2 === 0
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Html Code:

```
<div id="app">
        <li v-for="n in evenNumbers">{{ n }}</li>
</div>
```

Output:

```
2
4
```

Comment: This is a dup of many already answered questions in the Vue tag about this gotcha with Vue array updating. If someone comes across a better target dup ping me and and I'll update.

Comment: Because of my bad english, i did not understand. But i understand now because of your explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `Vue.set` or `vm.$set`, or replace the whole array with new one.

As [Vue Guide: Reactivity In Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) describes:

> Due to the limitations of modern JavaScript (and the abandonment of
> Object.observe), Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion.
> Since Vue performs the getter/setter conversion process during
> instance initialization, a property must be present in the data object
> in order for Vue to convert it and make it reactive.
>
> Vue does not allow dynamically adding new root-level reactive
> properties to an already created instance. **However, it’s possible to
> add reactive properties to a nested object using the Vue.set(object,
> key, value) method**

There are also a few **array-related** caveats, which already discussed in [List Rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data: {
    numbers: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
  },
  computed: {
    evenNumbers: function () {
      return this.numbers.filter(function (number) {
        return number % 2 === 0
      })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeData1: function () {
      this.$set(this.numbers, 0, 6)
    },
    changeData2: function () {
      this.numbers = [ 16, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<button @click="changeData1()">Update element with Vue.set or vm.$set</button>
<button @click="changeData2()">replace the whole array</button>
        <li v-for="n in evenNumbers">{{ n }}</li>
</div>
```